Identify distinct cases
I have a table with multiple columns (SQL Server). Only two columns are relevant to the question however.
Column a = ID (a numeric value)
Column b = Status (String)



ID
Status




100
Banana


100
Apple


101
Apple


102
Banana


102
Apple


102
Grape



I want to return only the rows which contain a single value of ‘Apple’ in this case this would be row 3, ID 101.
Although the other ID’s also have a value of ‘Apple’ I’m not interested in these as they have other values as well.
I’ve tried, combinations of IF, HAVING, with Case expressions and partitions. I thought I had it a couple of times but sadly not.
Here's one of my incorrect attempts:
SELECT 
    ID 
    , STATUS
FROM table name
GROUP BY ID, STATUS
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS) = 1 
AND MAX(STATUS) = 'APPLE'

And this:
SELECT 
    ID 
    , STATUS
    , IF(SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Apple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
OVER (PARTITION BY id) >0, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS Q_IDENTIFIER
FROM table_name


"I’ve tried, combinations of IF, HAVING, with Case statements and partitions." You forgot to demonstrate those attempts; that sounds exactly what you should be using.

My mistake, corrected now, sb 101

Can someone have multiple Apples?

Theoretically someone can have multiple Apples, so if we add ID 103, it could have two rows, both of which read Apple.

And you would want them included? Excluded? Would you expect 1 row or 2+?

There are a couple of ways of peeling this apple.
CREATE TABLE #Data (ID INT, Status NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Data
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    VALUES  (100, N'Banana')
    ,   (100, N'Apple')
    ,   (101, N'Apple')
    ,   (102, N'Banana')
    ,   (102, N'Apple')
    ,   (102, N'Grape')
) t (ID,Status)

Window aggregates:
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   COUNT(*) OVER(partition BY ID) AS totalCount
    FROM    #Data
    ) x
WHERE   Status = 'Apple'
AND totalCount = 1

This counts all rows for every ID ahead of time, which allows you to then filter out the desired rows outside of the subquery
Exists:
SELECT  *
FROM    #Data d
WHERE   Status = 'Apple'
AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT  1
        FROM    #Data d2
        WHERE   d2.ID = d.ID
        AND d2.Status <> d.Status
    )

This just checks so there are no other rows in the same ID-group. This can have downsides of returning duplicates if you have more than one Apple available.

By correlated logic
select * from tdata t1 where 1 =
    ( select count(id) from tdata t2
        where t2.id = t1.id and t1.status='Apple');

